# Not able to fetch data correctly from Google Sheet

Tags: json, swift, google-sheets, swiftui

I managed to fetch JSON data from Google Sheet, but it cause a fatal error:

> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error:
> Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue:
> "totalmarketvalue", intValue: nil),
> Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No
> value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue:
> "totalmarketvalue", intValue: nil) ("totalmarketvalue").",
> underlyingError: nil)): file

My struct and function listed below

```
struct PostTotal: Codable {
    // let id = UUID()
    var rows: [Layer0]
    struct Layer0: Codable, Hashable {
        var totalmarketvalue: String
        var totaltodaysprofit: String
        var todaysprofitpercent: String
        var totalasset: String
        var maxpurchasepower: String   
    }
}
```

```
func getTotalValue () -> String {
    let urlTotal = URL(string: webstringtotal)
    var results: String = ""
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlTotal!) { (datas, _, _) in
        let postss = try! JSONDecoder().decode(PostTotal.Layer0.self, from: datas!)
        results = postss.totalasset
    }
.resume()
    print(results)
    return results
}
```

[image: My JSON file structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can read this error like this:

```
No value associated with key "totalmarketvalue"
```

Which means the decoder can't find the `totalmarketvalue` key in your response.

It looks like you're trying to decode `PostTotal.Layer0` only:

```
let postss = try! JSONDecoder().decode(PostTotal.Layer0.self, from: datas!)
```

However, your input JSON has only two CodingKeys at root which is `columns` and `rows`. When you're trying to decode `PostTotal.Layer0` only, it expects the `totalmarketvalue` key at the top level.

You have to decode the whole JSON tree and then access the elements as needed:

```
let postss = try! JSONDecoder().decode(PostTotal.self, from: datas!)
let layer0 = postss.rows
```

---

**Notes**

If you fetch data from some external resource, you can't be 100% sure that the response will contain this key. Better use `do-try` and handle errors in case of missing data.

And note that you've specified `totalmarketvalue` of type `String`:

```
"totalmarketvalue": "100" // this will parse correctly
"totalmarketvalue": 100 // this will fail
```

You can also explicitly specify the type of your `CodingKeys`. This will allow you to keep your model variable names separated from the response model.

```
struct: Layer0: Codable, Hashable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { 
        case totalMarketValue = "totalmarketvalue"
        ...
    }
    var totalMarketValue: String
    ...
}
```

Comment: The "My JSON file structure" link is the JSON structure of my Google Sheet. And I am sure the totalmarketvalue type is string. And I found that there's intValue which is nil. I don't understand why the JSON data contains Int Value....

Comment: Thanks ! I use enum but it still shows

Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "totalmarketvalue", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"totalmarketvalue\", intValue: nil) (\"totalmarketvalue\").", underlyingError: nil)): file

There are stringValue: "totalmarketvalue" and intValue: nil, I don't know how this intValue comes from?

Comment: Please share your `datas` value, *before* you decode it.

Comment: The "datas" contains only one row.

{"columns":{"totalmarketvalue":["43,072,400.00"],"totaltodaysprofit":["330000.00"],"todaysprofitpercent":["0.77%"],"totalasset":["48,442,250"],"maxpurchasepower":["5,369,850.00"]},"rows":[{"totalmarketvalue":"43,072,400.00","totaltodaysprofit":"330000.00","todaysprofitpercent":"0.77%","totalasset":"48,442,250","maxpurchasepower":"5,369,850.00"}]}

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer. In short try to decode `PostTotal.self` instead of `PostTotal.Layer0.self`.